# Addional jQuery UI Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

jQuery UI and jQuery Tools provide some widget and controls. I am looking for additional jQuery UI Controls. Where can I get them? Please help.

Comment: What kind of controls are you looking for?

Comment: like toolbars, menus, panels, etc. I am also looking for a PHP "Form" class which provides both server side and client side validation.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all plugins get listed in http://plugins.jquery.com/

Beyond that, you can search the popular design blogs for lists of "[50 amazing jquery controls](http://www.noupe.com/jquery/50-amazing-jquery-examples-part1.html)" etc.